# PDO object rows printing twice

Tags: php, pdo

so I'm designing a web interface for a database but when I try to print the values from a query they come in doubles since they are counting 2 indices for the same value. Anyone know why this is happening?

PHP Code:

```
function loadTable()
{
    $name  = $_GET["table"];
    $db    = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=university", "root", "");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$name;
    $rows  = $db->query($query);

    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value)
        {
      print ($key.":".$value."<br>");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the output I get:

```
FM_ID:1234
0:1234
LAST_NAME:
1:
FIRST_NAME:
2:
OFFICE:Bliss 200
3:Bliss 200
EXTENSION:4455
4:4455
HOME_PHONE:5726952
5:5726952
MOBILE_PHONE:71283509
6:71283509
ADDRESS:
7:
EMAIL:
8:
STARTING_YEAR:2011
9:2011
TERMINATION_YEAR:2014
10:2014
LATEST_DEGREE:CMPS
11:CMPS
OBTAINED_FROM:AUB
12:AUB
DEGREE_YEAR:2014
13:2014
RESEARCH_INTEREST:Robotics
14:Robotics
```

Comment: Just curious, is you array that multidimensional that you need to nest 2 `foreach`s?

Comment: To be honest this is my first attempt at database querying, I nested 2 foreach's  so I can print the key and value for each row entry

Comment: if you print keys in first foreach, wouldn't you achieve the desired result

Comment: You want by the number of the column or by the name? You are basically looking for something called the *FETCH_MODE*, you can set the default mode as an attribute: http://php.net/pdo.setattribute (**`PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE`**) - As you're new, to PDO please make yourself comfortable with the manual first, e.g. read the introduction of the PDO chapter, then read about all the objects and methods you use in your code while you do so.

Answer (score 4):

try using

```
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

$rows = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

instead using `query`

Answer (score 4):

Im not sure if this would fix your problem but try something like this

```
$result_query = $db->query($query);
while($row = $result_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)))
{

}
```

you could refer for some tips here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php